# Clone a document fragment

Tags: javascript

Is there a short way to clone a document fragment (leaving the orginal fragment as it is)?

I can manually clone each node into a new fragment, but I guess there's a better way (?)...

```
let clonedFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
dFrag.childNodes.forEach(node => {
  const cloneNode = node.cloneNode();
  cloneNode.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
  clonedFrag.appendChild(cloneNode);
});
```

Comment: [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) inherits from [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), that means you can use `documentFragment.cloneNode(true)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, looks like you can. Like Teemu commented, it's a Node.

```js
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
const groupA = document.createElement("fieldset"); 
groupA.innerHTML = `
  <legend>Group A</legend>
  <p></p>`;
frag.append(groupA);

const clone = frag.cloneNode(true);
clone.querySelector('legend').textContent = `Group B`;

document.body.append(frag);
document.body.append(clone);
```